# Sed command to find lines in which all words start with a capital letter

Tags: sed

I'm studying the **sed** command. I have written a command which replaces the first letter of a word with a capital letter:

```
 sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

But I have no idea how to find lines in which all words start with a capital letter.

For example, my text file:

```
Hello world
Hello World
Lorem Ipsum sample
```

The command should return one line:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by matching lines that have at least one word starting with a lowercase character and deleting them:

```
sed '/\b[[:lower:]]/d' infile
```

`\b` is a GNU extension, so this requires GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new/ **that is all**. For anything else just use awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, portability, performance, etc...

Look:

```
$ cat file
Hello world
Hello World
Lorem Ipsum sample
Lorem ipsum Foo bar And stuff
```

Lines where every word starts with an upper case letter:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^| )[[:upper:]]/,"&") == NF' file
Hello World
```

Lines where 2 words start with an upper case letter:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^| )[[:upper:]]/,"&") == 2' file
Hello World
Lorem Ipsum sample
```

Lines where more than 1 words start with an upper case letter:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^| )[[:upper:]]/,"&") > 1' file
Hello World
Lorem Ipsum sample
Lorem ipsum Foo bar And stuff
```

Lines where the same number of words start with upper case as with lower case letters:

```
awk 'gsub(/(^| )[[:upper:]]/,"&") == gsub(/(^| )[[:lower:]]/,"&")' file
Hello world
Lorem ipsum Foo bar And stuff
```

Try taking whatever sed script you get in response to your question and building on it for the above (or any other!) cases if/when your requirements change.

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you need to match the whole line, i.e. `^...$`. This works for your example:

```
sed -E '/^ *(([A-Z][^ ]*) +)*[A-Z][^ ]*$/!d'
```

#### Explanation

- `*` - allow optional space at the start of the line
- `(([A-Z][^ ]*) +)*` - match capital letter followed by any number of non-space characters followed by one or more space. This whole group can be arbitrarily repeated
- `[A-Z][^ ]* *` - finally the line should end with a capitalized word followed by optional space
- the `!d` at the end deletes everyline that does not match the regular expression